# How to capture a OpenGL view as UIImage?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, uiimage

When I try to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129352/need-to-capture-uiview-into-a-uiimage-including-all-subviews) to convert a OpenGL view to UIImage, only the view's background is returned, but not the GLView content. How can I convert OpenGL's context into a UIImage?

Comment: I had the same problem and with the answers provided here I got a black screen. See my answer to this question to see how I finally got it to work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036288/xcode-screenshot-eaglcontext/11868013#11868013

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code to convert your `opengl` view in `UIImage` .

```
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);
 GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);
 GLvoid *pixel_data = nil;
 glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         (GLvoid *)buffer);
for (int y=0; y<backingHeight; y++) {
     for (int x=0; x<backingWidth*4; x++) {
         buffer2[y * 4 * backingWidth + x] =
     buffer[(backingHeight - y - 1) * backingWidth * 4 + x];
     }
 }
 CGDataProviderRef provider;
 provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2,
                                          backingWidth * backingHeight * 4,
                                          freeImageData);
 // set up for CGImage creation
 int bitsPerComponent = 8;
 int bitsPerPixel = 32;
 int bytesPerRow = 4 * backingWidth;
 CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
 // Use this to retain alpha
 //CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
 CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
 CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(backingWidth, backingHeight,
                                 bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel,
                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef,
                                 bitmapInfo, provider,
                                 NULL, NO,
                                 renderingIntent);
 // this contains our final image.
 UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

[Taken from](http://theocas.net/programming-shenanigans/2011/02/28/capture-apps-screen-ios/)

Comment: This renders black background.Can anyone help me,, why??

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what OpenGL view you are using. Since iOS 5 you can make use of GLKit and the corresponding GLKView that greatly simplifies the process of rendering an UIImage.

```
GLKView* v = (GLKView*) _previewViewController.view;
UIImage* thumbnail = [v snapshot];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the code. I find it usefull but I had to put some extra code in order to properly release allocated memory with buffer, buffer2, imageRef, colorSpaceRef and provider pointer. Note that buffer2 is released with provider release function.

```
static void myProviderReleaseData (void *info,const void *data,size_t size)
{
    free((void*)data);
}

- (UIImage*)renderToImage
{
    // The image size should be grabbed from your ESRenderer class. 
    // That parameter is get in renderer function: 
    // - (BOOL) resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer {
    // glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    GLint backingWidth = renderer.backingWidth;
    GLint backingHeight = renderer.backingHeight;

    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(backingWidth * backingHeight * 4);

    glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 (GLvoid *)buffer);
    for (int y=0; y<backingHeight; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x<backingWidth*4; x++) {
            buffer2[y * 4 * backingWidth + x] =
            buffer[(backingHeight - y - 1) * backingWidth * 4 + x];
        }
    }
    free(buffer);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2,
                                            backingWidth * backingHeight * 4,
                                        myProviderReleaseData);
    // set up for CGImage creation
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * backingWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Use this to retain alpha
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(backingWidth, backingHeight,
                                        bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo, provider,
                                    NULL, NO,
                                    renderingIntent);
    // this contains our final image.
    UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    return newUIImage;
}
```

Comment: This renders black background on the layer whereas i have already set my layer background to clear color in initwithcoder ?????