# get image from transformed ImageView objective c in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the code below, `img` is not a transformed image. How do I transform the image?

```
 CGAffineTransform transform = self.imageView.transform;

 if(transform.a == 1)
 {    
     transform.a = -1;
 }
 else
 {     
     transform.a = 1;   
 }

 self.imageView.transform = transform;

 UIImage *img = self.imageView.image;
```

This is the image:

[image]

After the transform, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you want the image to look like after the transform is applied?

Comment: jst like as in the imageView image....

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching it the wrong way. Something like this should work:

```
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

Comment: u can see the image before transform through this link.....http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/q71/988639_192688244227063_1733135779_n.jpg   /n and u can see the image after transform through this link.....http://sphotos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/q71/998366_192685424227345_883357333_n.jpg

Comment: Yes, I added that to your question. Does the code I posted help you at all?

Comment: Cheeky :) you should really check the existing orientation of the image before setting the new orientation...

Answer (score 0):

The transform is applied to the view, not the image. If you want an image with the transform applied you need to render the image view into a new image. Google "draw uiview into uiimage" or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=draw+uiview+into+uiimage.

Comment: CGAffineTransform transform = self.imageView.transform;

Comment: this is used for transform the image if we transform then how we get the tranform image

Comment: That is used to transform the view, which results in a change to the image ON SCREEN, but not in memory. To get the transformed image as a new image you need to draw the view into a new image. There are many posts on how to do that. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129352/need-to-capture-uiview-into-a-uiimage-including-all-subviews

Comment: how i post a image to you then u can understand my question.....i want to show you a example

Comment: You can upload an image somewhere and add a link to it here

Comment: http://sphotos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/q71/998366_192685424227345_883357333_n.jpg

Comment: image before transform

Comment: image after transform ......http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/q71/988639_192688244227063_1733135779_n.jpg

Comment: u can see the image before transform through this link.....http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/q71/988639_192688244227063_1733135779_n.jpg

Comment: So do you really need the image? Or you should just add the transformed image view to the screen and it will work?

Comment: i need a image after transform...