# How to capture a UIView as image which is out of currently visible frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Is there any way to capture a UIView to UIImage which is not currently visible or it is out of the frame. Below the code I am using now:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_myView.bounds.size, _myView.opaque, 0.0f);
[theView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_myView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Please check the answer on this thread,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4919804/4030948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)myView{ 
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, myView.opaque, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); 
     [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return image;
  }
```